# How to check if implicit or explicit cast exists?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have a generic class and I want to enforce that instances of the type parameter are always "cast-able" / convertible from String. Is it possible to do this without for example using an interface?

Possible implementation:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : IConvertibleFrom<string>, new()
{
    public T DoSomethingWith(string s)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Ideal implementation:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T DoSomethingWith(string s)
    {
        // CanBeConvertedFrom would return true if explicit or implicit cast exists
        if(!typeof(T).CanBeConvertedFrom(typeof(String))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

The reason why I would prefer this "ideal" implementation is mainly in order not to force all the Ts to implement IConvertibleFrom<>.

Comment: what's so ideal about an implementation that reacts to programming-time errors with runtime exceptions?

Comment: if you have a bunch of types that are already converting from string and you want to use them in a new class/method in the way I abstractly described, this would be the least-effort way to implement it. It would be a paint to go edit every type and implement the new interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you want to convert from the sealed String type, you can ignore possible nullable, boxing, reference and explicit conversions.  Only `op_Implicit()` qualifies.  A more generic approach is provided by the System.Linq.Expressions.Expression class:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
...
    public static T DoSomethingWith(string s)
    {
      var expr = Expression.Constant(s);
      var convert = Expression.Convert(expr, typeof(T));
      return (T)convert.Method.Invoke(null, new object[] { s });
    }
```

Beware the cost of Reflection.

Comment: I took the code as it is (but as generic method DoSomethingWith<T>()) and get a NullReferenceException: get_Method returns null.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(String))) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work either with implicit or explicit cast operators declared on argument type.

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure i follow you in your reply. that piece of code would throw an exception if `T` was an int, say, but not if it was a string or an object. is that not what you're after?

Comment: I tested it with class MyClass { public static implicit operator MyClass(string s) { return new MyClass(); } } and typeof(MyClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)) returns false. I assume you expected it to return true...

Answer (score -2):

Why can't you do something like this?

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : string
{
    public T DoSomethingWith(string s)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this way you can check whether `s` is convertible to `T` in the `DoSomethingWith` code. From there you can throw exception if it can't, or do the casting, if it can

Comment: Why use generics at all if you explicitly declare that the generic type has to be a string?

Comment: d, I declared `T` as must be derived from string, this is not the same as saying it must be string.

Comment: No, I have my own types that can be converted from a string. (PS: you can't inherit from string).

Comment: `string` is a sealed type, wouldnt compile.