# Conversion in .NET Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Where can I find conversion methods such as

```
    public static implicit operator MyType(OtherType d)
    public static implicit operator OtherType(MyType d)
```

in `Type` object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a type supports an implicit or explicit type conversion to another type with .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647075/checking-if-a-type-supports-an-implicit-or-explicit-type-conversion-to-another-ty)

Comment: It's important to note that you need to search for the method on both `MyType` and `OtherType` (including methods in base classes). And finally choose the correct one using C# overloading rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find operators if you ask a type for its methods. The method's [`IsSpecialName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isspecialname.aspx) property will return `true`. For example:

```
using System;

public class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator int(Foo input)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var method in typeof(Foo).GetMethods())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(method + ": " + method.IsSpecialName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here, really? The documentation for the "Type" class can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx

But what would be the default implementation of these in the `Type` object? There is no sensible conversion between e.g. a `string` and a `Type`.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but according to http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Csharp_implicit_operator.aspx the compiler generates as IL methods with the special name `op_Implicit` and the respective param type/result type.

So calling `GetMethods` on the Type should give you what you are looking for.