# How do I determine Int32 is in fact assignable from Int16

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a several `PropertyInfo` objects that represent properties of a target object. And a similar set of `PropertyInfo` objects that represent the properties of a source object.

My code assigns property values from source to target if the name and type matches. But some of the types are assignable but not exact match. One of the cases is source property of type `Int16` but on target side the property of same name is of type `Int32`. I use the [targetProperty.Type.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So in other words, the following is returning false while I really want it to give me a `true'

```
typeof(Int32).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Int16))
```

I have read other threads which suggest me that IsAssignableFrom is not what I need. Before I jump on to write a long switch-case code, I am checking to see if there is any easier way.

Comment: How many cases are you going to handle? [I found this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647075/checking-if-a-type-supports-an-implicit-or-explicit-type-conversion-to-another-t) if that helps.

Comment: @Guvante not too many. Int32, Int16, and may be a Int to double

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit conversion from `Int16` to `Int32` is a C# language feature, not a feature of the CLR or .NET, so they're not technically runtime assignable (although, to be fair, `IsAssignableFrom` would tell you that `object` is assignable from any value type even though you technically need a boxing conversion to do it).

There's no out of the box way I know to do this besides making a big honking switch statement like this:

```
public static bool HasImplicitConversion( Type source, Type destination )
{
    var sourceCode = Type.GetTypeCode( source );
    var destinationCode = Type.GetTypeCode( destination );
    switch( sourceCode )
    {
        case TypeCode.SByte:
            switch( destinationCode )
            {
                case TypeCode.Int16:
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                case TypeCode.Single:
                case TypeCode.Double:
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        case TypeCode.Byte:
            switch( destinationCode )
            {
                case TypeCode.Int16:
                case TypeCode.UInt16:
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                case TypeCode.UInt32:
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                case TypeCode.UInt64:
                case TypeCode.Single:
                case TypeCode.Double:
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        case TypeCode.Int16:
            switch( destinationCode )
            {
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                case TypeCode.Single:
                case TypeCode.Double:
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        case TypeCode.UInt16:
            switch( destinationCode )
            {
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                case TypeCode.UInt32:
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                case TypeCode.UInt64:
                case TypeCode.Single:
                case TypeCode.Double:
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        case TypeCode.Int32:
            switch( destinationCode )
            {
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                case TypeCode.Single:
                case TypeCode.Double:
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        case TypeCode.UInt32:
            switch( destinationCode )
            {
                case TypeCode.UInt32:
                case TypeCode.UInt64:
                case TypeCode.Single:
                case TypeCode.Double:
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        case TypeCode.Int64:
        case TypeCode.UInt64:
            switch( destinationCode )
            {
                case TypeCode.Single:
                case TypeCode.Double:
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        case TypeCode.Char:
            switch( destinationCode )
            {
                case TypeCode.UInt16:
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                case TypeCode.UInt32:
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                case TypeCode.UInt64:
                case TypeCode.Single:
                case TypeCode.Double:
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        case TypeCode.Single:
            return ( destinationCode == TypeCode.Double );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Int32 (int)` and `Int16 (short)` are Structs. Structs does not allow inheritances. Therefore `IsAssignableFrom` does not work because `short` does not inherit from `int`. But there is no problem in assigning a `short` to an `int`.

Comment: My code is dynamically testing the assignability and doing the assignment. I need to find out a way to say YES to assign from Int16 to Int32

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  It's just more details about the question.

Comment: Try using Convert and check fot IConvertable interface (I think it's the name of this interface)