# How to use variable type in as operator

Tags: c#, casting, propertyinfo, as-operator

For example:I have 2 variable (value ) & (property) i want to check is cast possible for value? We do not know the type of variables, How to check if cast is possible?

```
   var value = Reader[item];
   PropertyInfo property = properties.Where(x => x.Name == item).FirstOrDefault();
   var type=property.PropertyType;//Or property.ReflectedType
   var cs= value as type // Error: type is variable but is used like a Type
   if (cs!=null){
     ...
    }
```

Sample 1:

```
var value = 123;//is int
type = property.GetType();// is double
var x = (double)value;//Can be casted
```

Sample 2:

```
var value = "asd";//is string
type = property.GetType();// is double
var x = (double)value;//Can not be casted
```

Comment: if you don't know the type of the variables then you'll need to use reflection or the `dynamic` type.

Comment: @Aominè Is it possible to take an example?

Comment: You can use `Expression.Convert` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3647134/5311735

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`IsAssignable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Type_IsAssignableFrom_System_Type_):

```
bool isValidCast = type.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())
```

---

As per the comments about `int` to `double`:
I've made a mistake in my comment, so i deleted it.
`int` can be implicitly converted to `double` because there is a predefined implicit conversion, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table)

There are many ways to convert or cast from type to type. For example, You can use [implicit/explicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators), you can use [`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.7.1) or implement the `IConvertible` interface.

Now, you have to decide which use case is relevant to you. It can be a bit complex to check them all, especially without knowing the destination type at design time.

Comment: in this example  type.IsAssignableFrom return false but casting is possible:

`int value = 123;
double property = 123.200;
var type = property.GetType();
 bool isValidCast = type.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType());// false
var x = (double)value;//Can be casted`

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, type is a variable of type Type, hence why it is throwing that error. You can change your code to use Convert.ChangeType() instead. Something like this:

```
   var value = Reader[item];
   PropertyInfo property = properties.Where(x => x.Name == item).FirstOrDefault();
   var type=property.PropertyType;
   object cs= Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
   if (cs!=null){
     ...
    }
```

Notice that, since you don't know the strong type of your property at compile time, you still have to box it into an object type after changing its type. This means you wouldn't be able to access its properties and methods directly using dot syntax in code (e.g. cs.MyProperty). If you wish to be able to do that, you can use the dynamic type in C#:

```
dynamic dcs = cs;
Console.Write(dcs.MyProperty);
```

When using Convert.ChangeType() you have to make sure you are converting to the correct type. E.g.:

```
if (value.GetType() == type)
{
   object cs= Convert.ChangeType(value, type);   
}
```

Comment: in Convert.ChangeType() If it can not be cast, an error occurs

Comment: Yes, if, e.g., you try to convert string to int, it will throw error. But if, e.g., you convert int that is boxed inside object, it will work perfectly.

Comment: You have to be more specific about your problem. Have you ascertained the real type of your variable? From your code snippet, it is not clear how the variable value is related to property and its property.PropertyType. You might have acquired value from some source which returns it in string or some other format. In that case you should use other methods to convert it to your desired type.

Comment: Suppose the value is int `value=123` and type is `double` . the value has the ability to casting double. but `if (value.GetType() == type)` Makes the cast not happen

Comment: Number types are the only exceptions at language level. You can handle that special case in your code. E.g.: if (typeof(value) is int || typeof(value) is double)...