# How to check if an implicit conversion is available between types?

Tags: c#, casting, implicit

I need to check if an implicit conversion is available between types. For built-in types, I can create a dictionary with a type and list of corresponding available types. But for custom types this is not possible because I don't know on what code this will be checked. Is there a generic way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if implicit or explicit cast exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815452/how-to-check-if-implicit-or-explicit-cast-exists)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this. If for custom type defined method for implicit conversation, you will find it by "op_Implicit" name

> ```
> foreach (MethodInfo mi in typeof(CustomType).GetMethods())
>         {
>             if (mi.Name == "op_Implicit")
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine(mi.ReturnType.Name);
>             }
>         }
> ```

Comment: Note that the *inbuilt* types often don't contain operators - their conversions are done at the IL level. So while this is *part* of the answer, some conversions typically need to be hard-coded

Comment: This code with definitions for inbuilt types works great. Great thanks!

Comment: Thanks. However, is there any way to do this without reflection?

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried `IsAssignableFrom`?

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyOtherClass));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for implicit conversions. See also the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119441/check-if-types-are-castable-subclasses.

Comment: It's wrong! Long is assignable from Short, `long x = new short();`, but  `typeof(long).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(short))` returns False!